# How can I remove words with less than 3 characters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tf-idf

I am using `tf-idf` on text data, but am unable to remove words which are less than *3 characters*. I am using `stop-words` to ignore a few words, but how to specify the length to restrict words less than 3 characters?

```
stopwords = ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(['docx','45','ect', 'hou', 'com', 'recipient' , '030311' , '2011' , 'hrc' , 'qaddafi'])

vectsubject = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words=stopwords, max_df=0.50, min_df=2)
X_SUBJECT = vectsubject.fit_transform(datasetemail.MetadataSubject)
features_subject = vectsubject.get_feature_names()

# Let's print the top 5 terms in body
dfbodyfeatures = gettop5(features_subject)
print(dfbodyfeatures)
```

My result is having features with less than 3 characters.

```
0      aiding
1       syria
2      latest
3         sid
4    exchange
```

I want to remove words like "sid" and include the next feature in my result, so output could be to include "helping" feature which is next relevant feature

```
0      aiding
1       syria
2      latest
3      exchange
4      helping
```

basically, I want to remove features which are less than 3 characters in my `features_subject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following list comprehension should do the trick:

```
features_subject = [f for f in vectsubject.get_feature_names() if len(f) > 3]
```

Now the output should exclude any words of length less than 3:

```
dfbodyfeatures = gettop5(features_subject)
print(dfbodyfeatures)

0      aiding
1       syria
2      latest
3      exchange
4      helping
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
words = ['aiding', 'syria', 'latest', 'sid', 'exchange']
result_words = [x for x in words if len(x) > 3]

# Sample output
['aiding', 'syria', 'latest', 'exchange']
```